# How to connect Mysql database with WordPress files using dockerfile?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my docker compose file code

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  web:


    ports:
      - "80:80"
    build:
      context: ./code
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306
```

Here is my wordpress config file code

define( 'DB_NAME', 'testdb' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'user' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

and i got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXMF1.png)

I am new on docker your help will be appreciate able.Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) you can use as a base, it should be enough for a basic WordPress install. Personal preference, after messing around with docker I switched to lando, a docker wrapper, much more sane config then docker and you still have the option to config the .yml file as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

Change `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );` to `define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql' );`
localhost will resolve to within the docker and not the server hosting the dockers.